# Корректность выражения с предлогом

Tags: предлоги

Возможно ли следующее выражение? Ничего в нем не смущает (может быть, предлог)?

Прогуляться на пол часика.

Comment: _Владимир: Ничего в нем не смущает?_ === В первую очередь меня смущает пробел между "пол" и "часика"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Возможно ли следующее выражение? Ничего в нем не смущает (может быть,
>   предлог)?

Почему ж не смущает, очень даже смущает прогулка на некий пол некоего часика, тогда и предлог смутит: если прогулка, то по полу чего-л. (предбанника) или какому-л. (дощатому).

Ежели ж ненароком речь задумывалась о [получасье](http://ru-eval.ru/hist/xi-xvii/Vol16po/276.pdf), то возможен предлог **на**, равно как и **с**, равно как и **полное отсутствие** предлога:

*(пойти) прогуляться на полчасика — прогуляться полчасика — [Спросить у нее: можно ли прогуляться с полчасика или хозяева уже ждут?](https://books.google.ru/books?id=djyhonDdzdgC&pg=PT92&lpg=PT92&dq=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=E39NhL40ox&sig=ACfU3U3lZRKIVgU1naVfeAdERTjrMjpnBQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjbq5rQ5YPjAhWpw6YKHUw-BhoQ6AEwBnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0&f=false)*